# Php How to pass date and time to another .php file

Tags: php

I want to pass time and date which I get from user input to another php file using  but I dont know how to get the date and time input and pass it.

```
<a href="actionMAppointment.php?stu_id=<?php echo $row_RecEdit['stu_id'] ?>">Make Appointment (Test) </a> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Time:
        <input type = "time" id = "appointmentTime"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Date:
        <input type = "date" id = "appointmentDate"/>
```

Comment: do you search on google or try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your htm in a for with method GET

```
<form method="GET" action="your/url">
<a href="actionMAppointment.php?stu_id=<?php echo $row_RecEdit['stu_id'] ?>">Make Appointment (Test) </a> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Time:
        <input type = "time" id = "appointmentTime"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Date:
        <input type = "date" id = "appointmentDate"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```